# How to store the link of image in user profile into mysql db (without using BLOB)

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jakarta-ee

How to store the link of image in user_profile(JFrame) into mysql db (without using BLOB).
And how to retrieve these images respect to their primary key(like username) ?

I have already created JFileChooser and Swing application,
There 7 fields (username, name, password, address, mob no, email, sex and **Image**)
Now 7 fields (username, name, password, address, mob no, email, sex) are storing into database and image is storing into folder.Name of the image is (username.jpg).
80% is done here....
Now last 20%, I'm getting confuse. 
How to store the link of the image (like : src/img/john001.jpg) into database and how to retrieve that image . 
**There would be two buttons (upload and submit) 
Upload button will select and read the image where submit button will store the image into specific folder.** 
Please help me. 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: *"How to store the link of the image (like : src/img/john001.jpg) into database"* If there is a need to go that route, I'd probably look to use a `File` or a `String` representing a canonical path to the file.  Of course, the DB gurus are probably better off advising whether it *should* be a BLOB.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your images are stored relative to your classpath, you can store the absolute location of the images in the DB as a string (E.g. src/main/resources/img/john001.jpg)

Then in your code:

```
String fileName = getImageFileNameForUser(username);
InputStream image = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)